# Haven't learned calculus yet but I need this for a proof for Fibonacci numbers and its limit

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, fibonacci-numbers

In an infinite series of Fibonacci numbers, is this always true $$\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}>\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}$$? Can you make an argument that in an infinite convergent series, eventually that will be false?

Comment: Or at least that the interval will tend to 0 so there can't be one rational number that will always be inside that interval?

Comment: do you mean ? $$\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}>\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}$$

Comment: That's what's there, right?

Comment: $F_n+1 $ vs $F_{n+1}\\ $,which one do you want to use ?

Comment: Oh yeah $F_{n+1}$

Comment: For the standard Fibonacci sequence: $F_0=F_1=1$, $F_2=2$, it's false at the very beginning.

Comment: The ratio of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers is a convergent of the continued fraction $[1;1,1,1,1,\ldots]$ of $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. The sequence of convergents is never monotonic, but the sequence of convergents with even (or odd) indices always is.

Comment: $$ F_{n+1}^2- F_n F_{n+2} = (-1)^n $$ is straightforward to prove by induction, too.

Comment: See also: [Fibonacci ratio - inequality proof: $\frac{f_{2k}}{f_{2k-1}} < \frac{f_{2k+1}}{f_{2k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2542603) and 
[How do I prove $\frac{f_{2n+1}}{f_{2n}}>\frac{f_{2n}}{f_{2n-1}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3934894)

Answer (score 2):

hint :We know **$\color{red} {F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}}\\ \to \color{red} {F_{n}=F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}}$
$$\frac{F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}}{F_{n+1}}>\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}} $$
or see this $$\begin{bmatrix}f_{n+1} & f_n \\f_n & f_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n \to \det(\begin{bmatrix}f_{n+1} & f_n \\f_n & f_{n-1} \end{bmatrix})=\det(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n)\\f_{n+1}f_{n-1}-f_n.f_n=(-1)^n\\n=2k \to f_{n+1}f_{n-1}-f_n.f_n=+1 \\f_{n+1}f_{n-1}>f_n.f_n\\ \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}>\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n-1}}\\
n=2k+1 
\to f_{n+1}f_{n-1}-f_n.f_n=-1 \to f_{n+1}f_{n-1}<f_n.f_n \\ \to  \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}<\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n-1}} \to \\
\color{red} {\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n+1}}>\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_{n}}}$$ this is your case  when $n$ is odd

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the fractions $2/3$, $3/5$ and $5/8$ you'll see that the inequality you want isn't always true. In fact it alternates between being true and false. In the limit the sequence (not series) is the golden ratio. Every other term is bigger/smaller; the difference goes to zero.

You can find a proof on the wikipedia page 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Comment: I suspected this but thanks for confirming that I can use this in a proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}>\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}$$
is equivalent to
$$F_{n}^{2} - F_{n-1} F_{n+1} > 0.$$
Using
\begin{align}
5 \, F_{n}^{2} &= L_{2n} - 2 (-1)^{n} \\
5 \, F_{n-1}F_{n+1} &= L_{2n} + 3 (-1)^{n},
\end{align}
where $L_{n}$ are the Lucas numbers, then
$$-5 (-1)^n > 0$$
is the result. Only the odd values of $n$ make the given inequality true, ie
$$\frac{F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n+2}}>\frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}$$